# How are the risks of opening doors in-flight on airplanes different from opening doors on submarines underwater?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

Why is it considered dangerous or risky to open doors on an airplane during flight, while opening doors on a submarine underwater is generally considered safe?

What are the scientific factors that make it dangerous to open a door on an airplane during flight?

Comment: In flight, the air pressure inside an airplane is higher than the air outside. Opening a door will cause decompression. I'm not sure why you think it's _generally considered safe_ in the case of submarine, since in this instance water will flow inside. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Maybe the OP is thinking about a very fast moving submarine so that Bernoulli cancels the pressure difference :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Airplanes (submarines) operate in positive (negative) pressure relative to the surrounding air (water). The surrounding fluid pressure decreases (increases) with increasing height (depth) exponentially (linearly).

Airplanes are pressurized to 8000'. With an atmospheric half-height 16,000', the pressure difference is:

$$ \Delta P_A = (1\,{\rm atm})(2^{\frac{8000'}{16000'}} - 2^{\frac{35000'}{16000'}}) \approx
7\,{\rm lbs/in^2} $$

while a water pressure increases at (roughly) 1 atm per 10 meters. The estimated crush depth is 900 m (according to *a* search), so at maximum operating depth, the pressure difference is:

$$ \Delta P_S = (1\,{\rm atm})\frac{900\,{\rm m}}{10\,{\rm m}} = 1278 
\,{\rm lbs/in^2}$$

With a human's cross sectional is around 2400 square inches, the force on the body from the pressure differential for an open airplane (submarine) door is 8 (1500) tons.

On an airplane, with 8 tons of force, you are going out the door. You can't hold on like in the movies. Regarding the submarine, with 1500 tons, everyone in the sub dies instantly. Submarines at crush depth implode in milliseconds.

People have been sucked out of airplanes while other passengers witnessed it. Submarines have been lost at crush depth, no one survived to tell the tale.

A good example of the dangers of pressure differential is the Byford Dolphin accident, in which divers went from 12 atm to 1 atm as fast as possible (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byford_Dolphin). The mechanical force ejected the diver near the door, in pieces, some 30 feet, while divers in the bell suffered instant bubbling of, and lipids precipitating out of, their circulator systems. (don't look at the photos).